# Datepicker and JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, datepicker

I'm trying to just show specific days in jQuery UI datepicker. My code so far is from PHP getting `json_encode($result);`. The `$result` is from a SQL query. With jQuery, I now have the following code:

```
 $(function(){
    var today = new Date();
    $("#excursionDate").datepicker({
        minDate: today,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: excursionDates
    });
  });

   function excursionDates(date)
    {
        var day = date.getDay();
        var dayValues = [];
        $.get("getExcursionDay.php", {excursionId: 3}, function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                dayValues.push(parseInt(data[i].excursionDay));
            }
        }, 'json');
        if($.inArray(day, dayValues) !== -1)
        {
            return[true];
        }
        else
        {
            return[false];
        }
    }
```

For some reason I can't push values into the `dayValues` array. What could I do to solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: I hope their is no error in the `.php` file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json output of "getExcursionDay.php" ?

Comment: Yes ofc!
          [{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},{"excursionDay":"4"}]